# Conjugation notation, $gxg^{-1}$ or $g^{-1}xg$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, notation

In the short while that I've known what conjugation is, I've met both kinds of notation about equally often (and the slightly less common $x^g$ a couple of times as well), so  I am curious as to what is the difference between the two and whether they're equivalent. Is it a question of a purely stylistic nature, as, say, the choice $f(x)$ or $(x)f$?

Edit: Originally my question was about which of the 2 kinds of notation is more prevalent among MSE users, as I thought that they're 2 ways of denoting the same concept. I hadn't realised that it's actually 2 different definitions altogether, as opposed to simply a matter of notation; my thought process was that $g^{-1}x(g^{-1})^{-1}$ is the same as $g^{-1}xg$, i.e. having to do with what you take to be the "original" element, but apparently it has to do with the distinction between left and right actions.

My thanks to the other users for clearing this up!

Comment: Technically, it's not very much like $f(x)$ vs. $(x)f$ because $g^{-1}xg$ and $gxg^{-1}$ are not the same thing! Different textbooks pick different definitions, but must remain consistent with their choice throughout, of course.

Comment: It really is a matter of taste. Most algebraists use the right-to-left convention and so prefer to think in terms of right actions.

Comment: Fully agree with the previous comments. It is similar to defining the commutator $[g,x]=g^{-1}x^{-1}gx$ or $[g,x]=gxg^{-1}x^{-1}$

Comment: If you want $g\mapsto$conjugation by $g$ to be a homomorphism from $G$ to $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$, and you compose your functions right to left, then you want to use $gxg^{-1}$

Comment: It's *not* 2 kinds of notation, as already said (it would be if both were denoted, for instance, $c_g(x)$). It's two ways of defining conjugation of $x$ by $g$. Actually there are convenient shorthands: $gxg^{-1}={}^gx$, $g^{-1}xg=x^g$.

Comment: @NickyHekster so if one prefers left actions to right ones, and uses $gxg^{-1}$, which would be the corresponding commutator definition, the latter ($[g,x]=gxg^{-1}x^{-1}$)?

Comment: Correct, see the answer of Arturo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You generally want $x^g$ to represent $g^{-1}xg$. The reason is so that the "exponential notation" works:
$$(x^g)^h = h^{-1}(x^g)h = h^{-1}g^{-1}xgh = (gh)^{-1}x(gh) = x^{gh}.$$
If you were to use $x^g$ to denote $gxg^{-1}$, however, you get the wrong expression: $x^{gh} = ghxh^{-1}g^{-1} = (x^h)^g$.

That is why one usually sees ${}^gx$ used to denote $gxg^{-1}$.

Now, a different question is: when you say "$x$ conjugated by $g$", do you mean $gxg^{-1}$, or do you mean $g^{-1}xg$? The answer, unfortunately, is that it could mean either, depending on whether you like your actions on the left or on the right. The map $x\mapsto g^{-1}xg$ gives you a **right** action of $G$ on itself, whereas the map $y\mapsto gyg^{-1}$ gives you a **left** action of $G$ on itself.

They are both fine; it's a matter of what you prefer (like the commutator definition). Sometimes, other concerns affects your choice (much like the issue of "extension of $N$ by $K$", where people who do actions and representations prefer one meaning, and people who do varieties prefer the other). So long as you are consistent, you're fine, since a left action can be turned into a right action and vice-versa through an appropriate G-set isomorphism.

Note that if "conjugation by $g$" means $\varphi_g\colon x\mapsto gxg^{-1}$, then the map $G\to\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ given by $g\longmapsto \varphi_g$ is a homomorphism, since
$$\varphi_{gh}(x) = (gh)x(gh)^{-1} = g(hxh^{-1})g^{-1} = \varphi_g(\varphi_h(x)).$$
Whereas if "conjugation by $g$" means $\psi_g\colon x\mapsto g^{-1}xg$, then the map $g\longmapsto \psi_g$ is **not** a group homomorphism from $G$ to $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$, because you get
$$\psi_{gh}(x) = (gh)^{-1}x(gh) = \psi_h(\psi_g(x)).$$
So you get a map to $(\mathrm{Aut}(G))^{\mathrm{op}}$. This, and the fact that many people prefer left actions, is why in my experience $x\mapsto gxg^{-1}$ is *slightly* more prevalent.

Comment: Thanks for the illuminating answer, I hadn't considered that this might have something to do with group actions (my thought process was $g^{-1}xg$ is same as $g^{-1}x(g^{-1})^{-1}$, making the two 2 sides of the same coin).

Comment: Related to this (I think): should we say that the map $g \mapsto (x \mapsto xg)$ is a *homomorphism* from $G$ to $\operatorname{Sym}(G)$?

Comment: Oops sorry, I hadn't read carefully Arturo's answer till the end! +1

Comment: @Luca you've got the order wrong, it will be a homomorphism if you take left multiplication $g \mapsto (x \mapsto gx)$.

Comment: Exactly! As said in my 2nd comment, Arturo's answer closure makes it clear.

Comment: @V.Ch.: In fact, if $G$ has a left action on $X$, then you can use it to define a **right** action on $X$ by $x\cdot g = g^{-1}x$. Then $x\cdot(gh) = (gh)^{-1}x = h^{-1}g^{-1}x = h^{-1}(x\cdot g) = (x\cdot g)\cdot h$. Similarly, a right action allows you to define a left action by $g\circ x = xg^{-1}$. That's why the right action of conjugation by $g$ $x\mapsto g^{-1}xg$ corresponds to the left action of conjugation by $g^{-1}$, $x\mapsto g^{-1}x(g^{-1})^{-1}$.